# How to render mstyle elements using Mathjax in Android WebView

Tags: android, mathjax

I am working on an Android app that includes some MathML rendered using a local folder of the MathJax 2.3 package. (My setup essentially follows the Github guide [here](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-docs/wiki/Guide%3a-MathJax-in-Android-apps), with other irrelevant functionality.) I am using the HTML-CSS output from MathJax, testing with Android 4.1.2. At this point, I have only trimmed the MathJax package as recommended by the guide so that all functionality remains intact.

What I would like to do is include some mstyle elements (color, border, etc.) in the MathML that I upload. I have tried this on a [website using MathJax](http://www.compileonline.com/try_mathml_online.php) and it functions fine as far as I can tell. However, when I add these attributes to the MathML in my Android App, it stops rendering the images. Meaning it is most likely not an error with MathJax itself, but some compatibility error with MathJax specifically in Android.

**Edit:**

Here would be some example MathML code I load to the WebView:

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block">
<mstyle background='#9df' style='border: 1pt solid #000; padding: 2pt;'>
    <mn>1</mn><mo>+</mo><mn>2</mn>
</mstyle>
</math>
```

After doing so, I get no response from the WebView, meaning no error messages from MathJax and nothing out of the ordinary in the Android message logs. However, as soon as I load something that does not contain any mstyle elements (no color, background, or border attributes), like below:

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block">
<mstyle>
    <mn>1</mn><mo>+</mo><mn>2</mn>
</mstyle>
</math>
```

it renders fine.

**End Edit**

Any ideas on this problem would be appreciated. I will try to add more contextual information here as it is requested.

Thanks all!

Comment: Do you have an example of some MathML code that exhibits the problem? Also, are you getting any error messages from MathJax when rendering fails?

Comment: I added some edits above, hopefully that clarifies the problem a bit. But no, I don't see any MathJax errors. They would show up in a small text box in the bottom left corner of the WebView, right?

Comment: Thanks for adding the information; nothing wrong with those so I'm guessing it's an Android (unless you stripped MathJax too much). If you're building on the sample apps mentioned on the Github Wiki page you linked to, these have issues on recent Android versions, see [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mathjax-users/android%7Csort:date/mathjax-users/85Fc_ad4qAs/HSdBbIS_HAAJ).

Comment: Ya, most of my MathML is generated programmatically, and I've copied/pasted most things after proving they work in that test site I linked, so I'm confident the MathML is correct (if it weren't, or if I trimmed too much of MathJax, I think I'd see an error too). I didn't know there were issues in more recent versions though, not a problem for me but something to keep in mind for sure.